# Why Access denied when removing files/folder on Windows

Tags: security, windows-7, authentication

What does really happen when I try to remove a folder on windows (7, 2008, 2012)
and get the "famous":

```
You need permission to perform this action
...
Folder Access denied
```

What I've done :

- I granted "Everyone" on the folder
- I tried to delete it under LOCAL SYSTEM (psexec)
- I ran `chkdsk /f` before (no issue).

Nothing works, but software like [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) !
 (By the way, It tells me that no one is handling the folder)

It does the job, but could you tell me more about this behavior?

(And what kind of trick Unlocker does apply to just make it right ??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is User Access Control (UAC). If you give modify or greater permissions to Users then you can avoid this prompt. You could also disable UAC. Or better yet, don't mess with folders that you shouldn't be messing with, Microsoft purposely put this prompt in to avoid normal users hosing their system.